# where to store decision trees and multiple regression models?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I have implemented decission tree and multiple regression models. I am planning to deploy it and have access to calculate/classify something by rest. Will use most likely rest from python. The only question is how to and where to store those models. Should I store them in mongo and a json or? I dont want to everytime to create model when request to classify something is coming. I know that keras/tensorflow is stored easily on Amazon. What about more trivial algorithms?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Model Persistence](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html) chapter in the scikit-learn _User Guide_?